# AngularJS the scope value does not display in the views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie in angularjs; the scope value are not displaying in the views.

I have two apps: myApp and ram - each one having their controllers.

I'm trying to display scope values.
Only myApp shows values but ram does not.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
  <br>
  Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<div ng-app="ram" ng-controller="myCtrl2">

  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName2"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName2"><br>
  <br>
  Full Name: {{firstName2 + " " + lastName2}}

</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
  });

</script>

<script>
  var app2 = angular.module('ram', []);
  app2.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName2= "ram";
    $scope.lastName2= "babu";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you can't have two ng-apps on one page. If you want to do that, use angular.bootstrap instead.

Comment: You have to bootstrap the modules to have multiple ng-app in page.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bootstrap modules to have multiple ng-app in your page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="App1" ng-app="shoppingCart" ng-controller="ShoppingCartController">
        <h1>Your order</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <span>{{item.product_name}}</span>
            <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
            <button ng-click="remove($index);">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="App2" ng-app="namesList" ng-controller="NamesController">
        <h1>List of Names</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="_name in names">
            <p>{{_name.username}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
            var shoppingCartModule = angular.module("shoppingCart", [])
            shoppingCartModule.controller("ShoppingCartController",
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.items = [
                        {product_name: "Product 1", price: 50},
                        {product_name: "Product 2", price: 20},
                        {product_name: "Product 3", price: 180}
                    ];
                    $scope.remove = function(index) {
                        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                }
            );
            var namesModule = angular.module("namesList", [])
            namesModule.controller("NamesController",
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.names = [
                        {username: "Nitin"},
                        {username: "Mukesh"}
                    ];
                }
            );
            angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"),['namesList']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use two apps on the same page. If you do that then you will need to use Angular Bootstrap.

First assign your second div an id e.g id ="ramID" to something like below

```
<div id="ramID" ng-app="ram" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
```

then add this line to your code to your script

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("ramID"),['ram']);
```

hope it helps.